# Application is crashing when creating a options Dictionary used by addPersistentStoreWithType method

Tags: app-store, core-data-migration, nspersistentstore, keychainitemwrapper, encrypted-core-data-sql

I am using `encrypted-core-data` to encrypts all data that is persisted , previously simple `CoreData` was using. `persistentStoreCoordinator` creation code are as follows .

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *oldStoreURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"VistaJetApp.sqlite"];
NSURL *newStoreURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"VistaJet.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *currentPassword = [[VJAesCryptoWrapper getInstance] getCurrentPassword];
NSDictionary *options = [self getEncryptedStoreOptionsWithPassword:currentPassword andDatabaseStore:newStoreURL];

_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

//if old store not exists , it means fresh installation
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:oldStoreURL.path] == NO) {             
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType configuration:nil URL:newStoreURL options:options error: &error]) {         
    }        
} else {

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:oldStoreURL options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error: &error]) {                     
    }

    NSPersistentStore *oldUnsecureStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:oldStoreURL];
    [ConsoleLogger logText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Migration started"]];

    //start migration
    if(![_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:oldUnsecureStore toURL:newStoreURL options:options withType:EncryptedStoreType error:&error]) {


    } else {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:oldStoreURL error:nil];
    }

}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;

}
```

Creation of options dictionary

```
- (NSDictionary*)getEncryptedStoreOptionsWithPassword:(NSString*)password andDatabaseStore:(NSURL*)storeUrl {
return @{ EncryptedStorePassphraseKey: password,
          EncryptedStoreDatabaseLocation: storeUrl,
          NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES
          };
}
```

I am saving password in keychain using `KeychainItemWrapper` and my code crashing exactly on `getEncryptedStoreOptionsWithPassword:currentPassword` method. App is live and I am not able to reproduce the crash , but on crashlytics it is showing so many crashes

[crashlytics crash logs image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HOR95UtUKU2Jm-e0s1mMLLQtdXjBAVoB/view?usp=sharing)

Also using `AESCrypt` to encrypt  password then saving it to keychain using `KeychainItemWrapper`.

**Observation:**
The crash that crashlytics is displaying only appear when we upload build on test flight using distribution profile.

crash is happening 100% on iOS 11 as reported by crashlytics

Comment: could this be a duplicate of this known bug??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561041/keychainitemwrapper-crash-on-ios10

Comment: @Popmedic I tested on iOS 11 and later and I am unable to reproduce the issue , In crashlytics all the affected users have iOS 11 and later , any steps to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: :-( Sorry, was hopeful this was it, I hate when I have a bug that I can not reproduce.  I don't think it will hurt to turn on keychain sharing, and if the crashes go down after release, maybe it is a similar defect, might be worth a try.

Comment: @AliAKhtar thank you so much for posting ur question. you really saved my DB migration activity time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a known bug in iOS 10 that you are seeing, there is a work-around: enable "Keychain Sharing" (under your app -> Capabilities tab in Xcode).

[KeychainItemWrapper crash on iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561041/keychainitemwrapper-crash-on-ios10)